# How can I get the class object from its member variable?

Tags: java

I'm currently working on this code, I want to pass an ID to a member function to get the object.

```
public class Car {

   private int _ID;
   private String name;
   private String model;

   Car(int _id, String name, String model){
       this._ID = _id;
       this.name = name;
       this.model = model;
   }

   ....

   public static Car getCar(int _id){
       Car mCar;
       //TODO: Algo to get car
       return mCar;
   }

}
```

Is there any way I can get the object in this way?

Any help is appreciated!
Thank You!

Comment: I think it is not clear what you want to do!

Comment: what algo u r asking for?

Comment: I would like to pass in the _id of a car to get the details of the car. Then use the details to print to screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to keep a `Map` of objects by key. Here's one way to do it:

```
public class Car {

   private int _ID;
   private String name;
   private String model;

   Car(int _id, String name, String model){
       this._ID = _id;
       this.name = name;
       this.model = model;
       carsById.put(_id, this);  // <-- add to map
   }

   ....

   private static Map<Integer, Car> carsById = new HashMap<>();

   public static Car getCar(int _id){
       return carsById.get(_id);
   }

}
```

Comment: As some have mentioned, this may not be the best approach from a design standpoint, but in this case I believe it's the simplest way to demonstrate the solution.

Comment: this works, but i would like to know if there is any other method! is there?

Comment: @hello_world There are various ways to do it, but they would all involve caching your objects in a collection of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

There's no predefined way to do that. You'd have to have `Car` or something else maintain a `Map<Integer,Car>` or similar of cars. This would usually be best done **not** in `Car` itself, but in the code using it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a list (or map or tree or anything else suitable) of created `Car`, it's not possible with your current code only. A good practice is to separate this list out of `Car` class, maintained elsewhere. But if you insist, shmosel provides one way.